# Serialization issue on WebLogic

Tags: java, serialization, weblogic

One of my classes does not implement Serializable when I run my code on local server (Jetty), That time it is running fine.(WithOut Implementing Serializable, code is running fine on Local Server)

But when I deploy it on weblogic then it is giving me Error as:

```
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException:
```

When I implement Serializable to that particular class then Error is gone on WebLogic.

Any idea why it is happening?

**Stack Trace for Error**

```
<65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766596> <BEA-000000> <Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: com.example.usecase.command.version.VersionSearchCriteria; nested exception is:
        java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.usecase.command.version.VersionSearchCriteria>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766597> <BEA-000000> < at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:350)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766598> <BEA-000000> < at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:252)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766599> <BEA-000000> < at com.example.Starter_5i7spw_EOImpl_1002_WLStub.evaluateCommand(Unknown Source)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766600> <BEA-000000> < at com.example.taco2.service.impl.CallcomServerService.callServerWithCommand(CallcomServerService.java:178)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766601> <BEA-000000> < ... 40 more>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766602> <BEA-000000> <Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.usecase.command.version.VersionSearchCriteria>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766603> <BEA-000000> < at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1087)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766604> <BEA-000000> < at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1382)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766605> <BEA-000000> < at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1354)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766606> <BEA-000000> < at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1296)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766607> <BEA-000000> < at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1085)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766608> <BEA-000000> < at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:304)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766609> <BEA-000000> < at weblogic.rmi.extensions.server.CBVOutputStream.writeObject(CBVOutputStream.java:91)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766610> <BEA-000000> < at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.copy(ServerRequest.java:238)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766611> <BEA-000000> < at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:166)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766612> <BEA-000000> < at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:335)>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766613> <BEA-000000> < ... 43 more>
####<Tracing Data here> <01.05.2012 09:02:46 CEST> <Error> <HTTP> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-000000000000003d> <1335855766617> <BEA-101020> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@eff17d - appName: 'taco2', name: 'taco2', context-path: '/taco2'] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:384)
        at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:318)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
        at com.example.taco2.common.AuthorizeFilter.doFilter(AuthorizeFilter.java:65)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
        at com.example.enterprise.beasecurity.AuthenticationFilter$1.run(AuthenticationFilter.java:150)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.security.Security.runAs(Security.java:41)
        at com.example.enterprise.beasecurity.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:147)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
        at com.example.taco2.common.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:36)
        at com.example.taco2.common.Taco2EncodingFilter.doFilter(Taco2EncodingFilter.java:27)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
>
####<01.05.2012 09:02:50 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-0000000000000004> <1335855770431> <BEA-000000> <01.05.2012 09:02:50 - WARNUNG      : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'jms/elu.AnswerQueue2' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Error creating bean with name 'elu.connection.target.factory2' defined in class path resource [at/example/abc/kernel/beanContext/abc.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup 'jms.com.example.elu.ConnectionFactory2' didn't find subcontext 'jms'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'jms/at/example/elu/ConnectionFactory2'>
####<01.05.2012 09:02:50 CEST> <Error> <System.err> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-0000000000000004> <1335855770433> <BEA-000000> <>
####<01.05.2012 09:02:50 CEST> <Info> <System.out> <example> <coms1m1vm1> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <com> <> <65d8f2366e4156e8:6d5e12f8:137072e8ad2:-8000-0000000000000004> <1335855770436> <BEA-000000> <<<exampleTimeDebugInfo>>MeteredStream.isToRotate: [STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' time=2012-05-01 09:02:32.435 creationTime=2012-05-01 09:02:29.335 CurrentTime=Tue May 01 09:02:50 CEST 2012>
^Z
```

Comment: I all depends what you try to do with the object. When does the exception occur - show the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because WebLogic is actually serializing the object for the remote call in case there are multiple servers, while Jetty doesn't and uses EJB local interface.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably deploying it over RMI (differently from using Jetty) and it needs to serialize something.

Start Weblogic with this flag

```
-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true
```

and it will show you what's happening.

Edit: my reading of the stack trace is that Weblogic has clustering enabled, where sessions are serialized to allow transfer between cluster nodes.

Comment: I have added the stacktrace please explain me why it is not giving me on the local and only on weblogic